# Run NUnit test on Ubuntu from command line

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, nunit

How to run NUnit test on Ubuntu from the command line?

I've created file OnlyTest.cs

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Framework;

[TestFixture]
public class OnlyTest
{
    [Test]
    public void MyTest() 
    {
        int a = 10;
        Assert.AreEqual(10, a);
    }
}
```

According to article [Running NuGet command-line on Linux](http://headsigned.com/article/running-nuget-command-line-on-linux) I've downloaded files NuGet.exe and Microsoft.Build.dll

I've run NuGet to install NUnit

```
    $ mono NuGet.exe install NUnit
    Installing 'NUnit 2.6.4'.
    Successfully installed 'NUnit 2.6.4'.

    $ ls -lR
    .:
    razem 1668
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 mw mw   28861 cze 24 23:45 Microsoft.Build.zip
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 mw mw 1664512 cze 24 23:42 NuGet.exe
    drwxrwxr-x 3 mw mw    4096 cze 25 00:29 NUnit.2.6.4
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 mw mw     208 cze 25 00:27 OnlyTest.cs

    ./NUnit.2.6.4:
    razem 108
    drwxrwxr-x 2 mw mw  4096 cze 25 00:29 lib
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 mw mw  1131 cze 25 00:29 license.txt
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 mw mw 99004 cze 25 00:29 NUnit.2.6.4.nupkg

    ./NUnit.2.6.4/lib:
    razem 720
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 mw mw 151552 cze 25 00:29 nunit.framework.dll
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 mw mw 584600 cze 25 00:29 nunit.framework.xml
```

Since I'm not sure about compiling and running

Compiling hadn't produce any errors

```
 mcs OnlyTest.cs -target:library -r:NUnit.2.6.4/lib/nunit.framework.dll -out:OnlyTest.dll
```

But when I try run nunit I get errors like

```
$ nunit-console OnlyTest.dll -noresult
NUnit-Console version 2.6.0.0
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment - 
   OS Version: Unix 3.16.0.30
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.17020 ( Mono 4.0 ( 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1.1) ) )

ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
Execution Runtime: mono-4.0
Missing method .ctor in assembly /[MY_PATH]/OnlyTest.dll, type NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute
Can't find custom attr constructor image: /[MY_PATH]/OnlyTest.dll mtoken: 0x0a000001
Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=2.6.4.14350, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' or one of its dependencies.
```

The same goes for `nunit-gui`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=2.6.4.14350, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77'
```

Check which nunit-console/nunit assemblies that are installed... I assuming it is picking up old assemblies in the GAC.

Lets start from the beginning:

Get the latest and greatest NUnit **AND** it's Runner tools

```
curl https://api.nuget.org/downloads/nuget.exe -o nuget.exe
mono nuget.exe install NUnit
mono nuget.exe install NUnit.Runners
```

Make sure the mono is finding those assemblies first (vs the GAC)

```
export MONO_PATH=${PWD}/NUnit.Runners.2.6.4/tools:${PWD}/NUnit.2.6.4/lib
```

Create your test example and compile it:

```
vi OnlyTest.cs #Using the example in your question
mcs OnlyTest.cs -target:library -r:NUnit.2.6.4/lib/nunit.framework.dll -out:OnlyTest.dll
```

Run it:

```
mono ./NUnit.Runners.2.6.4/tools/nunit-console.exe OnlyTest.dll -noresult
```

Output:

```
Using default runtime: v4.0.30319
NUnit-Console version 2.6.4.14350
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment -
   OS Version: Unix 14.3.0.0
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.17020 ( Mono 4.0 ( 4.3.0 (master/b044a27 Thu Jun 18 15:17:08 PDT 2015) ) )

ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
Execution Runtime: mono-4.0
.
Tests run: 1, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 0.0280499 seconds
  Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  I can also use `nunit-gui OnlyTest.dll`. Great step-by-step explanation, I had only change `$(PWD)` to `$(pwd)`.

Comment: BTW, I have `OS Version: Unix 3.16.0.30, CLR Version: 2.0.50727.1433 ( Mono 3.5 ( 3.2.8` Which PPA is used for getting Mono 4?

Comment: I added another answer in order to point you to the latest mono packages for Unbuntu...  I build from source: Mono JIT compiler version 4.3.0 (master/b044a27)

Comment: If I get "The 'NUnit 3.11.0' package requires NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.60717.93'" when trying to run `mono nuget.exe install NUnit` does this mean there is an additional CLI tool like NuGet client which needs to be installed/updated?

Answer (score 0):

FYI: I build mono from source as I'm on OS-X and the official disto is still 32-bit.

Getting the the latest and greatest on Ubuntu:

Debian, Ubuntu, and derivatives
Add the Mono Project GPG signing key and the package repository to your system (if you don’t use sudo, be sure to switch to root):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Run a package upgrade to upgrade existing packages to the latest available. Then install Mono as described in the Usage section.

Note: While the APT package is built against Debian Wheezy, it is compatible with a number of Debian derivatives (including Ubuntu) which means you can use the same repository across all these distributions.

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives